# Access iterable by key

Tags: php, oop, iterable

Is it ok to access [`iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) type by key?

This code works fine, but it seems to contradict basic idea of "iterability", doesn't it?

```
function (iterable $a){
    return $a['b'];
}
```

The problem that I see is that PHP has `ArrayAccess` interface for classes, but nothing to generalize idea of "array access" with arrays.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Xatenev extended my question :)

Comment: You haven't understood what the `XY Problem` is. Read the link. You should ask "Currently I want to do X and im trying to solve it with PHP's iterable/ArrayAccess because Y. How can I do this? This is my current code {...}" and instead you are asking "I am trying to use ArrayAccess for arrays(?)" which is broad and non-understandable and misses a ton of context. What are you **really** trying to do? How does your data structure look like? Atleast for me, this question is not answerable at its current state.

Comment: @Xatenev I need general type for `array` and `ArrayAccess`. Currently it's `iterable` by implementation. But in docs there is nothing about array access for iterables. Therefore I'm not sure if I can use `iterable` for this case :)